# Remove a character from a search and return the correct item that contains the character

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

After searching a while and coming up empty I decided to post in hopes someone can help send me to the right direction.

I am attempting to figure out a way to return a result that contains a hyphen while removing it from the search query. Some items may return multiple hypens

I.E.

Searching 
020550407

would return the correct item(s) 
-02055-0407 
-02055-0407-1

There isn't a pattern to where each item has the hyphen, so it I need to be able to remove it from anywhere in the search query.

I've tried a couple different things, all with no luck.

Examples:

```
results = (from x in results
           where x.item.Replace("-", "").Contains(NumberSearch)
           select x);
```

---Or---

```
results = results.Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(NumberSearch, x.item)==1);
```

---Or---

```
var result = (from x in results
              where SqlMethods.Like(x.item, NumberSearch)
              select x)
```

Among other things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would do a results.ToList() to get everything client side then try the same linq query against the list. If you get nothing, that cannot be blamed on the generated SQL.

Comment: When removing hyphens while searchings from the source data you are presumably building something extremely slow. If you want it easy and with a fast(er) search store a version of the data without hyphens also in your data store and search via that column.

Comment: @Ralf The correct way to store some of these items is with a hyphen.  I just want to be able to search without the hyphen if need be.  The database I am using is read only, and has 100,000s of items in it, so I can't really edit the data source directly.

Comment: i was recommending to store both versions one with and one without the hyphens not replacing the current data in the current column. Any version that will remove hyphens in the data while searching will render indexes on that column useless for the search. Means it will be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. This should work:

```
results = results.Where(x => x.item.Replace("-", "").Contains(NumberSearch)).ToList();
```